# Lebesgue integral of continous function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$ be a measure space. Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, be a continous function with
$$g_n(x)=g(x^n)\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x), \qquad x\in \mathbb{R}, n\in \mathbb{N}.$$
I need to calculate
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int g_n d\lambda$$
And I am not sure if I have done this correct, since it depends on the function $g$, anyways, I have done the following:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int g_n d\lambda &=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int g(x^n)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x)\lambda(dx)\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} R\int_0 ^1g(x^n)dx \qquad (g:continous)\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[g(x^n)x\right]_0^1=g(1).
\end{align}
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. Compute the pointwise limit of $g_n$
2. Use a theorem to change limes and integral.

Comment: When you say pointwise limit of $g_n$, is that the following $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} g(x^n)\cdot1_{[0,1]}(x)=\begin{cases}
g(1), x=1\\
0, x\not = [0,1]\\
g(0), x \in [0,1)
\end{cases}$

Comment: Yes, that is it. The pointwise limit is a simple step function whose integral can be computed. And if you can exchange limes and integral, then you are done. But therefore you have to refer to a theorem.

Comment: Could you confirm if this is correct, I get:\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int g(x^n)\cdot1_{[0,1]}(x)\lambda(dx)&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}R\int_0^1 g(x^n)dx\\
&=R\int_0^1 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}g(x^n)dx\\
&=\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}xg(x^n)\right]^1_0=g(1)-g(0)
\end{align} Where I use that $g$ is continous and monotone convergence.

Comment: That is still wrong. How do you integrate with the limit? That is nonsense. First, you definitely have to check the monotone convergence theorem which madprob refered in his answer. And then $\lim_{n\to\infty} g_n = g(0)1_{[0,1]}$ almost everywhere, so $\int \lim_{n\to\infty} g_n(x)\lambda(dx)=\int g(0)1_{[0,1]}(x)~\lambda(dx)=\ldots=g(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What is the limit of $x^n$ as $n\to\infty$ and $x\in[0,1]$?

Comment: It goes towards 0, if $x\not = 1$ Could you elaborate on this? Where do I need to use this?

Comment: You need it in order to find out what happens to $g(x^n)$ in the limit. The continuity of $g$ will be needed, too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the passage $\lim_{n}\int_0^1{g(x^n)dx}= \lim_{n}xg(x^n)\big|_{0}^{1}$. This equality is generally false and I don't think this approach will help you.
The other answers suggest that you might be able to obtain, instead,
$\lim_{n}\int g_n(x)dx = \int \lim_{n}g_n(x)dx$.

The standard results for passing the limit into an integral are the
[monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) and [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).
For this problem, you can use the latter. You need to:

1. Find an integrable function, $h(x)$, such that $|g_{n}(x)| \leq h(x)$.
2. Find a function, $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=\lim_{n}g(x^n)$.

For (1), you can use the continuity of $g(x)$ and the fact that $g_{n}(x)$ is $0$ outside of $[0,1]$ to find $h(x)$. For (2), you can use the continuity of $g$ to obtain that, for every $x \in [0,1]$, $\lim_{n}g(x^n)=g(\lim_{n} x_n)$.
Once you verify these conditions, then you obtain
\begin{align*}
 \lim_n\int_0^1 g_n(x)dx
 &= \int_0^1 \lim_n g_n(x)dx
 = \int_0^1 f(x) dx
\end{align*}